# The method or operation is not implemented exception even after assembly was installed in GAC

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly

I am having an issue with WPF where an early version of an assembly is loaded into my application so let's say an Xceed.WPF.Toolkit but v.2.0. I got an extension to this application that I am writing that needs a newer version of the toolkit let's say v.3.4.

I thought that while installing the plug-in for the app which adds extra functionality to the base app, if I add the new v.3.4 of Xceed to GAC it will be able to parse the XAML using new controls available in that assembly and all will be fine. However, I keep getting this:

[image]

My assembly is clearly installed in the GAC:

[image]

Is there a way to make the new assembly version discover-able via GAC that I am missing?

I tried using `Assembly.LoadFrom()` before my WPF `InitializeComponent();` is called but even though the assembly loads fine it still throws the XAML exception when initialized.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Thank you for the suggestion to use Assembly Binding Log Viewer. I was able to extract the following log from it. The main application when the Xceed toolkit is loaded binds to version 3.0 with the following log:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (3/17/2019 @ 12:19:24 AM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2019\Revit.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Program Files\Dynamo\Dynamo Core\2\nodes\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Revit 2019/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Revit.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2019\Revit.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Dynamo/Dynamo Core/2/nodes/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Program Files\Dynamo\Dynamo Core\2\nodes\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4
LOG: Re-apply policy for where-ref bind.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Where-ref bind Codebase does not match what is found in default context. Keep the result in LoadFrom context.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Program Files\Dynamo\Dynamo Core\2\nodes\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in LoadFrom load context.
```

Then that is followed by my extension attempting to load a 3.4 version with the following log:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (3/17/2019 @ 12:19:29 AM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2019\Revit.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.0\packages\archi-lab.net\bin\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Revit 2019/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Revit.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2019\Revit.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Dynamo/Dynamo Revit/2.0/packages/archi-lab.net/bin/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.0\packages\archi-lab.net\bin\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4
LOG: Re-apply policy for where-ref bind.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4
LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
LOG: Switch from LoadFrom context to default context.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit\v4.0_3.4.0.0__3e4669d2f30244f4\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Can anyone help me understand what these mean?

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe, log all the binds.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the suggestion. I never used that utility before but it looks very useful. I have edited my answer to show the two logs when first version is loaded, and then when I am attempting to load in the second version. Can you help me understand the logs? I am not sure I can make much out of them.

Comment: @konrad: Did you try to add a [<bindingRedirect>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) to your App.config?

Comment: I did, and that works really well when I redirect a range ie. 0.0.0.0-3.4.0.0 -> 3.4.0.0. However, the code that I am writing is an extension for a 3rd party application, and the main process is not owned by me. I would prefer to not modify someone else's app.config. Is there a way to create such binding redirect from within my own DLL, or by installing it in a GAC?